# Full timeline of a question

Tags: support, status-completed, questions, revisions-list

Is it possible to see the full chronological timeline of a question *including* when comments were added or edits were made.

As best I can tell, at the moment you can only see the edit history of a question.  What I would like to be able to do is see something like this:

13:00 - Question created
13:10 - Question edited
13:15 - comment added to question
14:00 - Answer submitted
14:30 - additional comment added to question
14:40 - comment added to answer

Is this possible / does it already exist???

(I hope this makes sense...)

Comment: Non-relevant comment added to question.

Comment: why would this be useful? What need does it serve?

Comment: I was trying to follow how a particular discussion had evolved. What appeared to have happened was an answer was put up and marked as helpful, but then as the conversation evolved and other answers and comments were posted the original answer was no longer helpful and dropped down the list out of site. Based on the information attached to the original question and the accepted answer, I could not understand why the given answer was accepted.  It was only after I scrolled through the full list of responses and mentally reconstructed the timeline that I understood why the final answer.

Comment: In hind site, I guess what I was looking for was a more traditional threaded view of the questions, answers and comments to help reconstruct the conversation.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Half a year later, Jon's answer isn't true anymore. There is an [experimental timeline feature on the sites now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view). Being experimental, it's not part of the UI yet, but it's pretty much what you requested. It works like this:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/QUESTIONNUMBER/timeline
```

I have a little bookmarklet set up to view the timeline of the question I'm currently looking at:

```
javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href.replace(/questions\/(\d+)\/.*$/,"posts/$1/timeline");
```

Comment: Thats fantastic.  Thanks for the heads up.  Its exactly the sort of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't available within the web UI, but you could do it retrospectively with the data dump if there was something you were particularly interested in.

(I'm not sure whether the data dump contains deleted posts/comments though.)

Of course, if we ever end up with a Wave robot which spots all of these things happening, you'll be able to see the change history that way :)

Comment: Thanks Jon. It was more of a general question, as sometimes following the conversation (so to speak) can be difficult with the different answers, edits, and comments.