# Question RSS feed should only give new changes

Tags: bug, status-declined, feed

When subscribing to an RSS feed of a question (via the `question feed` link) you've typically read all the existing answers/comments on that question and want to be notified of any changes. What happens now is that you get the top 30 items currently posted (including the question, you can't subscribe to a question unless you already saw it!).

Question RSS feeds should include a time stamp and only post stuff that's later than that time.

Comment: Wait, what? Isn't this just how RSS works and it's the job of the feed reader to show only new changes?

Comment: @Cawas, it's the feed read's job to show un-viewed items, if you subscribe to a new feed it will show you the `N` last items which are (in this case) irrelevant.

Comment: @Motti Ok, what if someone just bumped into that question, want a feed of it for read later, and just go and click on the link without reading the HTML?

Comment: @Cawas, that seems to be a very strange use-case, you subscribe for feeds of questions that you're interested in, if you just want to read it later you would just **star** it (or use something like http://www.instapaper.com)

Comment: Well, doesn't things like instapaper actually use this feature then?

Comment: I think there's a way to please both sides here, but I don't think the current Question RSS feed show the comments.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really agree Question RSS feed, or any feed for that matter, should worry about showing recent items. It should always show every item and leave the rest to the aggregator. But maybe it could give an option, such as https://meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/question/22374?startdate=yyyy-mm-dd to filter out everything before that date.

*I hope I'm not going too off-topic on the lines below.*

As a side note, I just went to a old question that got several updates and even by ordering it by Newest or Oldest it's got hard to keep track among answers and comments.

While RSS doesn't solve this issue, I think it could if it added comments on it (currently the feed doesn't show the comments). So we could see answers and comments mixed in the order they were posted.

So the Question RSS should look a lot like the question expanded [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/22374/timeline). It's a hidden feature I [just found out about](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36738/any-feed-for-stackoverflow-that-also-has-comments-in-rss/36740#36740), even if it's [been around for a little while](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view).

The timeline is also a [perfect example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14643/full-timeline-of-a-question) of another basic feature that's available in places SO is using as reference such as Digg, Wikipedia, but the developers don't see any reason to implement it at first.

Answer (score 2):

No RSS feed I know of behaves this way..