# Is there a feed for Stack Overflow that also has comments in RSS?

Tags: stack-overflow, feed, discussion

Stack Overflow question feeds by default don't provide updates for comments.  What's the solution to this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the experimental timeline feature. It's not linked anywhere yet, so you have to type the URL yourself:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/[question number]/timeline
```

e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/36738/timeline for this one. It does include comments. But remember that it's experimental; in particular, there's **no corresponding RSS feed** (yet?).

Comment: Can we use yahoo pipes to accomplish this task. I mean making a custom RSS

Comment: Isn't pipes just an aggregator? If so, you'd still need an original RSS feed that includes comments.

Comment: Just use Google Reader, you can subscribe to any page now, so subscribe to timeline.

Comment: but google reader doesnt prompt me the instant i get a comment

Comment: @Michael Haren: I don't think that's true. Do you have an example? I have never noticed a comment that was hidden in the timeline view.

Comment: @balpha--you're right, my bad

Comment: Eh, google reader cannot update the created feed properly :(