# Add a "modified" sort order for answers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sorting answers by activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22481/sorting-answers-by-activity)

I like to use the *newest* sort order for questions like the suggestion of domain names for new SE sites (and for all in my case, it's my favorite sort order).

Sometimes I see new activity on the homepage, but the activity was the edition of an old answer, so I have to scroll and search through the multiple pages of the question, and it's a pain. (or click on the user that made the change, go to his activity tab, and click on the revised post for a direct link, also a pain)

Could we have a "last modified" sort order?

Comment: Late to notice, but this is somewhat of a duplicate of [Sorting answers by activity](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22481/sorting-answers-by-activity).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's 2 methods that you can use as a workaround to see the most recent modifications made. On the right, underneath "asked" and "viewed" is "latest activity", with a supplied time. Clicking on the time will navigate you straight to the most recent activity that occurred, including edits to posts. You can accomplish this also, when viewing the front page, by clicking on the time stamp that is shown for the latest activity, to the left of the username displayed. This is a very, *very* weak workaround, though, especially in the example you've just cited in tracking the domain names.

That said, I think a "last modified" or "active" sorting method on answers would be very nice to have. It's more relevant in the Meta sites than it is in the parent sites, but the utility that we'd get on the Meta site is worth it, I believe. Not to mention, it'll end up leaking to the parent sites for the rare occasions where it would be useful.

---

This has [recently been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22481/sorting-answers-by-activity/48488#48488) as the Active sort, which replaces the old Oldest sort.

Comment: ah, very cool, didn't know I could click the timestamp. Although it's a mini-workaround as I can only do that for the latest modification, not the last 3 for example.

Comment: @Juan Yes, it's a very weak workaround, especially in scenarios like the domain name where it would be more useful to see more than just the most recent one.

Comment: @Juan, that timestamp thingy has been around since February. See [Recent feature changes on Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-on-stack-overflow/59446#59446)