# "Least recent first" instead of "Most recent first" answer ordering

Tags: feature-request, answers, up-votes, answer-order, sorting

*Edited:*

When sorting by Votes, all else being equal (up votes /  whether answer has been edited or not / how many comments the answer has, etc), I *think* answers are ordered in "most recent first" order. I suggest this be changed to "least recent first" (all else being equal of course). Reason:

Lets say **A** answered a question   at 22:34:00. At 22:34:30, **B** gave almost the same answer, perhaps sufficiently differently worded. (**B** might not do this intentionally). And assume both answers are correct.

Now, the asker, and anyone else, are very likely to up-vote **B**'s answer (usually much less ppl would go on to vote **A**'s answer also as it is lower down the order). Clearly in this case, it is **A** who deserves more up-votes.

(Note that the scenario is not so uncommon, and likely to happen when many people rush to answer a simple question. I have been the benefactor in some cases, never counted if I ever 'lost out').

Comment: Infact, so far, I have seen that the secondary sorting key when sorting by Votes is "last activity". (If vote counts are equal, it shows most-recent-first). Becuase of the reasons I mentioned, it should be least recent first.

Answer (score 2):

You can already sort by "oldest" (note however that "newest" has been replaced by "active"):

[image]

But if you mean when sorting by votes answers on equal votes are sorted randomly.

Comment: I usually have my default as "votes" - so yes, I meant when "sorting by votes". I usually always saw "most recent first" when sorting by votes. Didn't know it was random. I am not sure on benefits vs negative points of ignoring secondary keys.

Comment: *Oldest* appears to have been replaced with *active* as of today, this is the very reason I came to meta, I'm struggling to understand why.

Comment: Found the link - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22481/sorting-answers-by-activity/48488#48488

Comment: *Leaving this answer as a CW answer for reference only* — and because this sorting order might come back, [I really hope](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71561/bring-back-the-oldest-sort-order-for-answers)!

Comment: Do people actually use those tabs?

Comment: @IAbstract - I use "active" (I used to use "newest") mostly. I do use the others from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

> When sorting by Votes, all else being equal (up votes / whether answer has been edited or not / how many comments the answer has, etc), I *think* answers are ordered in "most recent first" order.

No, that's *only* true [when there's more than 1 page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18655/random-sorting-appears-to-screw-with-answer-permalinks/18938#18938) of answers. If there's no pagination, then equal voted answers are "sorted" randomly.

Comment: Yup, its random. I think it should be least recent first, so that the early bird has the better chance to get its prize. Imagine two 0 voted answers - there is 50% chance that the second poster gets the first vote, and goes on to get more votes (well less than 50% because some people might actually take the care to see posting time - but you know what I mean).

Comment: @JP19, too bad: if the team would go for that reasoning, it would not have removed the "oldest" sort order either. And I guess I agree with the team for the randomization in the "votes" order: when sorting on votes you explicitly *want* to know what others think, and the equal voted posts are, er, equal then? (I don't like they took the "oldest" away though, but [maybe we can get that back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71561/bring-back-the-oldest-sort-order-for-answers)...)