# What happened to "oldest first" when viewing answers to questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, answers, sorting

Just like I miss the Stack Overflow "show me all of the most recently changed questions" homepage, my "oldest first" sort order for answers also went away recently (and not just on Stack Overflow, but all Stack Exchanges).

Why are such useful things just going away? Sure, they might not be optimal (and the currently decided optimal view should be the default for non-logged in users and new accounts), but it's getting old having my preferences being yanked away suddenly and then having to get used to something new.

Comment: If it interests you, there's a [feature request to bring it back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71561/bring-back-the-oldest-sort-order-for-answers).

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71561/bring-back-the-oldest-sort-order-for-answers

Comment: I almost downvoted for *they might not be optimal* ;-)