# Answer sort order: oldest *and* newest?

Tags: feature-request, answers, sorting

Any chance we could have both 'oldest' and 'newest' sort orders? I used to use 'newest' all the time to keep up with new posts on questions that have gathered a lot of responses (or a few long ones).

Scrolling all the way down and potentially having to change pages makes it hard to find new answers.

Comment: Well now as a dev, you can do it yourself. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Active is pretty close to newest. If there are no edits then the most active answer will be the same as the newest and hence first on the list.

If there are edits then the most recently edited answer will be first on the list. This is probably a better sort order as you don't have to go hunting through all the answers looking for the most recently edited one.

Comment: This is indeed [Jeff's motivation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71561/bring-back-the-oldest-sort-order-for-answers/75301#75301): *I agree that "oldest" is more unique than "newest", in that "active" is very similar to newest in practice. So I replaced "newest" with "oldest" [...]*

Comment: I would personally like to see newest come back again. If someone is just tinkering with their answer, that's not of nearly as much interest to me as a completely new answer. I'm fine with "active" being available, but I'd like "newest" back as well.

Comment: I'm actually with @Jon on this - I'd like "newest" back, but will live with "active".