# How to read all of the questions of a tag in chronological order

Tags: discussion, tags, sorting, feed

I would like to read all the questions under a particular tag in chronological order. My objective is to be able to do that in reversed feed kind of way, so I can keep tabs on what I have read.

Beginning at the last page of a tag is an obvious solution; however, the number of pages under a tag is dynamic and in some cases ([c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [java](/questions/tagged/java), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)) changes very rapidly. Using the website to read the tags would involve a lot of manual bookkeeping.

What would be a better way to do this? I am not familiar with the Stack API, but I am willing to write a tool to do this. Please advise.

Comment: What exactly is it you way to do here? Trying to read the entire c# and java tags in ascending order is... unrealistic. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @MarcGravell: That was the intention, to read all C# and jQuery tagged questions.

Comment: that is a vast amount of data; why not just use the data dump?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Thanks for  your guidance. Would  you explain the data dump a little bit, please? What and how.

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/cc-wiki-dump/

Answer (score 3):

Sort by `newest` and head to the last page.

Answer (score 2):

First, there already is an RSS feed, sorted by time, available at `https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=[INSERT TAG NAME HERE]sort=newest`.  For example:

- [C# RSS Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=c#&sort=newest)
- [Java RSS Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=java&sort=newest)
- [jQuery RSS Feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=jquery&sort=newest)

They are sorted by newest -> oldest, but most RSS readers have a 'reverse' function.

Alternatively, a feature request could cause clicking on the tab to alternate between newest first and oldest first, as suggested in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71561/bring-back-the-oldest-sort-order-for-answers/71701#71701).  However, your best bet for now (especially if you want to read large amounts of Q&A) is to use a feed reader.

Comment: Reversing the feed would be an obvious choice but google reader only shows feeds from last 30 days when sorted oldest to newest. Any suggestions for an  alternative feedreader?

Comment: @fallow - That (*"What feed readers can sort a full RSS feed oldest-to-newest,"* not *"What's an alternative feedreader"*) is a question for Superuser or Webapps (see [this question](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/6194/whats-the-best-way-to-read-through-the-archives-of-a-blog), looks useful in your context).  There are many feed readers, this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_feed_aggregators) shows some 60 different tools.

Answer (score 1):

The list of questions tagged with a tag is already shown in chronological order; you cannot sort them from the older to the newer, though.

The following screenshot shows what I see when I click on [drupal](/questions/tagged/drupal).

[image: Screenshot of Tagged Questions sorted by age.]