# Tag feeds in chronological order

Tags: discussion, tags, feed, sorting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read all of the questions of a tag in chronological order](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106076/how-to-read-all-of-the-questions-of-a-tag-in-chronological-order)

I would like to read all the questions under a particular tag in chronological order. My objective is to be able to do that in reversed feed kind of way, so I can keep tabs on what I have read.

Beginning at the last page of a tag is an obvious solution; however, the number of pages under a tag is dynamic and in some cases ([c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [java](/questions/tagged/java), [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)) changes very rapidly. Using the website to read the tags would involve a lot of manual bookkeeping.

What would be a better way to do this? I am not familiar with the Stack API, but I am willing to write a tool to do this. Please advise.