# Bring back the 'newest' sort order for answers

Tags: feature-request, answers, sorting

I am not advocating removing any existing sort, but please also bring back the `newest` sort order for answers.

Newest is the best sort order there is for finding the best answer.  The reason for this is that often the answer with the most votes simply has the most votes because it is old and appears first by default (it is likely a very good answer, but maybe not the best).

I currently use "oldest" sort order and immediately start scrolling to the bottom to find newer answers with lots of votes since these are typically very good and up to date answers (and often have improvements on the highest-vote answer).

And for those who think `active` is a good replacement for `newest`, you are wrong.  `Active` is garbage for the purpose I stated above, since all edits throw off my "algorithm" for finding the best answer -- I end up having to manually inspect all the dates, which is slower than just using oldest sort.

Comment: Why is the newest *posted* answer any more likely to be an improvement on the highest-voted answer(s) than the most recently *edited* answer? While a large number of edits may be for more trivial things like formatting and grammar, I'm not particularly convinced that edits that improve the content are significantly less common than new answers that actually add something substantially better than what's already present.

Comment: I wouldn't mind having additional sorting methods, or toggling the sort order by clicking the same sort again. But I'd hate to see Oldest or Active go.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Are people that opposed to having more options?

Comment: @TimStone I don't believe I said the newest answer would be better than the one with the most votes.

Comment: @TimStone *"I'm not particularly convinced that edits that improve the content are significantly less common than new answers that actually add something substantially better than what's already present*" I think you misunderstand me.  In my mind, old editted posts showing up above new posts is a problem since often those edits don't contain any useful content and it throws me off.  Also note that I am not advocating getting rid of any existing sort.

Comment: @Arjan I am not advocating removing any existing sort... I guess people are getting the wrong idea... :(

Comment: Voting might just indicate folks don't find the newest sort order that important (and would rather have the team spend time on [something else](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request)). (I wouldn't downvote for that, as additional sorts wouldn't bother me, but [voting is a bit different here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).) Or people might disagree with your analysis.

Comment: I think you are perceiving the same importance for being able to find newest answers that I do: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235102/finding-questions-with-the-newest-answers-anywhere-on-site

Answer (score 3):

Do you have evidence that shows that the oldest answers have the most upvotes?  How often does this occur? Is it often enough to justify pushing the truly great answers to the bottom, simply because they may or may not be recently posted? If you had some statistics, I think it would maybe help you make a stronger case for changing something that works really well, IMHO.

I don't have any stats handy myself, but my impression is that this is *not* a problem. Most of the questions I answer on StackOverflow get anywhere from 1 to 4 answers, on average, in my experience.

The older list style polling questions -- which are now considered off topic or not a good fit for StackExchange -- are the only exceptions I can really think of. If you're having to scroll through more than 10 answers to try to find that true gem, then the question most likely isn't a good fit for the StackExchange platform and should probably be flagged and reviewed by the community.

With that said, the only way I could see the StackExchange team accepting this request is if the system worked as follows:

- The default sort view is *always* as follows: Accepted answer first, followed by highest voted.
- Users can toggle the view on a question to sort by votes, using a `sort-by` tab at the beginning of the set of answers.
- However, the sort order resets to the default view once leaving the page. The emphasis is always on answers sorted by what the community judges to be the best answers.
- Additionally, this feature is made available *only* to users who reach a certain reputation threshold, which helps ensure users understand how the system works, that the community's collective, crowd-sourced voice determines what appears at the top of the page.

Comment: see related answer at http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/75301/1

Comment: Oh my, I must be blind. I've never seen those tabs before (i.e Active, Oldest, Votes).  But that's just because I've never needed them. I don't look at the cartoon questions or anything where I would ever have a need to sort. This feature could not exist and I wouldn't know the difference ;)

Comment: *"the sort order resets to the default view once leaving the page"*, please, no, it's working just fine for me now.

Comment: *"Do you have evidence that shows that the oldest answers have the most upvotes? How often does this occur?"* It happens on almost every popular question with answers spanning a large period of time, I'm surprised you haven't noticed. *"Is it often enough to justify pushing the truly great answers to the bottom, simply because they may or may not be recently posted?"* That's a weird question... one could ask the same of the `oldest` sort -- Is it fair to push great answers to the bottom because they are new? The answer is no, in fact, we should favor newer answers.

Comment: As it is, newer answers get very little consideration on old questions with lots of answers, and having a "newest" sort could help reverse the trend.