# Finding Questions with the Newest Answers anywhere on Site?

Tags: feature-request, search, sorting, filtering, new-answers

Accessing Questions via ***your own*** Newest Answers (or by Votes or Activity) is easy to do using functionality already present on your user profile (see below).

[image]

However, I have not yet found a similarly easy way (i.e. two clicks) to find the Questions which have the Newest Answers ***anywhere on an entire Stack Exchange site*** (i.e. not just for a single user via their profile) .

Is there one?

As mentioned in a related Q&A ([There should be a filter for new answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190086/there-should-be-a-filter-for-new-answers)?):

> The *activity* tab is a poor way to track new answers. It contains
>   edited questions, new questions, and even questions bumped by
>   Community.

Comment: So we need to find the newest answers that are unquestioned so we can question them? If you want to review answers, use the review section. Notice the review section is only offered to users with specific amounts of rep.

Comment: What you're basically asking for is still searching for *questions*, but sorted by "questions with the newest answers". The question is still the top-level entity.

Comment: @AvnerShahar-Kashtan That's exactly it, but I have also just overhauled my question to try and make that much clearer to the wider audience.

Comment: You can access them from profile (<https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/215590/polygeo?tab=answers&sort=newest>)

Comment: @hjpotter92 That's still only the Questions with ***my*** Newest Answers.  What I am requesting is how to find the Questions with the Newest Answers by ***any user*** on the site.

Comment: Related feature request (not sure if duplicate): [There should be a filter for new answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190086/). There's some workaround there, by the way. ... I generally like  your proposal, but I think it  would be better received if you did not  suggest to add to The Five (plus one) Items in the main navbar. Some things are sacred.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. I've updated my question and I think you are right about the related feature request (and it not being a duplicate).

Comment: Do you mean [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer)?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Doing it with favorite tags is not part of my question and what you provided certainly seems to return the Newest Answers in exactly the way I am after.  Its not two GUI clicks, but is easy to add as a browser favourite so if you post it as an Answer here I will happily Accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [suggested workaround in another answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235132) is nice, but as noted in the comments on that won't get the same kind of use as a tab would

I am sure many people - both content contributors and readers would find it useful to read recently posted answers without having to wade through recently asked questions and recently edited posts (both of which show up on the "active" sort).

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the Search mechanism which provides the `is:answer` operator, then sort by Newest, e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aanswer

This will effectively give all answers on a site, sorted by answer date.

Comment: This helps, but it does not have the same effect to the majority of users (who usually does not use the advanced search options) that it would have if we had separate tabs for edits: one for editing activity (title, tags, questions, answers) and another for new answers. My hypothesis is that having this feature by design there would be more voting (specially on smaller sites).

Comment: @AndreSilva true, but until those features are added (if at all), I fear this is the only viable option.