# Highest Votes for Answers

Tags: feature-request, answers

I just love looking at the highest ranking (votes) questions to see how I can improve my questions. I'm trying to look for the highest ranked (votes) answers ***overall*** out of all the tags, but there seems to be no option for that. Of course here is the highest questions page:
[image]

Could we have the same type of page but with the highest ranked answers? Question score don't count just the answers. It would be great to see how people make high quality ***answers*** so others like me can make better answers.

Comment: You are asking a question along similar lines to one I posed a while ago to make it easier to find the Newest (rather than most Voted) Answers on a site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235102/finding-questions-with-the-newest-answers-anywhere-on-site

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you search for the search term [`is:answer` and sort by votes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3Aanswer), they will be sorted by votes on the answer.

Comment: Obviously not everyone would know that. That's why I explained it.

Comment: Never mind. Thanks for the great answer!