# Can we get a "Newest" tab on the default page?

Tags: feature-request

Currently, if you go to any site SE site, you're met with 5 tabs: Active, Featured, Hot, Week, Month. However, if you break it down by specific tags, you get a new tab: Newest. Can we get this tab on the default page as well? It's really disconcerting when you visit an SE site, and see a question at the top of the page, only to realize the reason it's there is because it was edited to have tags removed.

Default:
[image: Default Page]

Tag:
[image]

Comment: ...this is actually already available when you click on the [questions "tab"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions) (depending on your last selection).

Comment: Isn't the "default" page on sites a list of questions based on specific algorithms? Such as edits, our fave tags, etc. So, having a "sort newest" button doesn't make sense, that is what the questions tab is for surely?.

Comment: @James Only on SO. On all other sites, the front page is sorted purely by activity.

Comment: I think this is closely related to an earlier Q&A: [Finding Questions with the Newest Answers anywhere on Site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235102/finding-questions-with-the-newest-answers-anywhere-on-site)