# View history of changes

Tags: support, questions, revisions-list, edits, diff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does Editing work in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work-in-stack-overflow)

How do I view the changes made to a question, in the SO-style visual diff?

I'm sure I've seen this before, but the "history" button eludes me. Clicking "edit" gives me a drop down of the revisions, but not the actual diff.

---

**Edit**

This edit is a demonstration of the revision history functionality.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work-in-stack-overflow

Answer (score 19):

Click the part that says `edited [some time] ago` under your question. That brings you to [the revision page for this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/38647/revisions). I have edited your question as a demonstration.

#### JavaScript bookmarklet

You can also install yourself [this little bookmarklet](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14643/full-timeline-of-a-question/38592#38592) to view the revision history of a question:

```
javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href.replace(/questions\/(\d+)\/.*$/,"posts/$1/revisions");
```

#### URL format

In general, for any post (question or answer), grab the ID and swap it out in the following format:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/{postID}/revisions
```

Comment: +1 That's a good edit!

Comment: How to see history of edits of answers? Clicking `edit` for answer doesn't bring you `the revision page`