# StackOverflow's "close > off-topic" reasons could be improved

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions, off-topic

*Off-Topic* close reasons should always include ways to fix the problem and alternative websites, if the question is unfixable. Current options:

- > Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](https://superuser.com/about).

  Good.
- > Questions concerning problems with code you've written must **describe the specific problem** and include valid code to reproduce it. See [SSCCE.org](http://sscce.org/) for guidance.

  Technically, it is not off-topic, but an incomplete question. It's hard to choose between this option and *unclear what you're asking* option.
- > Questions must **demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved**. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

  Again, not off-topic; again, too close to *unclear what you're asking* option.
- > Questions on **professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/about).

  Good.
- > Questions asking for **tool or library recommendations** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. [Describe the problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.

  So-so. While it gives suggestions how to make the question appropriate for SO, it does not provide alternatives, and in case of tool and library recommendations, the answer to "what have you done so far" is often "googled and found A, B and C". The linked question on meta is quite specific.
- > This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

  So-so. It again suggests Super User, so it is duplicate, but not Server Fault (no consistency).

On the whole:

1. Options *describe the specific problem* and *demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved* (essentially "what have you tried?") should be moved as sub-options of *unclear what you're asking*.
2. An alternative should be added for *tool or library recommendations* option. That is, if there is any good website for comparisons like on Wikipedia ("C# vs Java", "Text editors" etc.) It should probably also be a sub-option of *primarily opinion-based*, because that is exactly what it is.
3. A list of another sites in the SE network should include Server Fault. Maybe it should include other sites, but I don't know statistics.
4. Period is missing in two of the options.

Comment: I think the overlap with Code Review is worth a special call out. Code snippets are frequently submitted to SO with a request for help in making them "better" in some way, typically clearer, DRYer, etc. This is arguably in the domain of Code Review, but the implementation of this policy seems arbitrary. Is "functional correctness" the only legitimate topic for code feedback on SO? What about performance?  See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185842/is-the-title-considered-part-of-the-question for an example.

Comment: In general, I think the "off topic" wording suffers from the same problem that the "not a real question" wording did previously. The typical English interpretation of what the words mean is much narrower than the category definition. I realize that this question of taxonomy has received a lot of work/attention, so I don't want to glibly suggest a specific alternative, but it would be nice if the breadth of the wording matched the breadth of the category.

Comment: Can you tell me where you found the detailed documentation you reviewed? All the SO help and FAQ pages I've been able to find still point to the old taxonomy.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I've just clicked the "flag" link under a question on SO.

Comment: Regarding the recommendation link: I'd actually like to switch that up for [something like this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad), but I'm letting that discussion bake for a bit more. Also, you can find some additional discussion of the specific off-topic reasons here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185142/what-should-the-predefined-off-topic-reasons-be-for-stack-overflow

Comment: "Technically, it is not off-topic, but an incomplete question. It's hard to choose between this option and unclear what you're asking option." <-- well, no, technically, it's off-topic, because the off-topic reasons includes that, in fact, verbatim. And we're saying incomplete questions are off-topic, and have no intention to start incompletequestions.stackexchange.com, but if we did, they might be on topic there.

Comment: @djechlin "incompletequestions.stackexchange.com" *moseys on over to Area51....* ;)

Comment: When reviewing I find it confusing that _"incomplete"_-reasons are under off-topic. It's simply not the same thing.