# Why are some posts tweeted?

Tags: support

1. Why are some posts tweeted?  Is it done by someone, or
   automatically?
2. I find some posts are tweeted only when they are edited by some
   others, and I click the edit history. When a post has not been
   edited, I can't see the edit history and don't know if the post has
   been tweeted. How can we know if such a post has been tweeted?

Comment: Here's how to view the post history even if the button is not there. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/38648/260841

Comment: I don't think an edit actually _causes_ a tweet, I would assume the "history" page is just a way to view when it was tweeted, though, I have no evidence to support this assumption.