# Why doesn't the history say who, or what, deleted this question?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions, revisions-list

I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2926611/331508) (need 10K rep to see it), and when I checked it just now it was not closed but was deleted.   It's fine that it's deleted, Stack Overflow is better because of it, but there is none of the usual accounting.

[image: Delete-by info is missing]

That is, it doesn't say *who* deleted it.  The deletion does not show in the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2926611/revisions), and the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14643/148310)   [returns a 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2926611/timeline?asc=True).

Here is the current history for the question:

[image: Missing from history too]

---

---

For reference, **here is what it usually** (¿Is supposed to?) **looks like** on [a typical deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1/where-oh-where-did-the-joel-data-go) (10K link):

[image: Good deletion data]

And [its history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1/revisions):

[image: Good History]

---

**What happened with that question; why is the usual history info missing?**

Comment: [Another case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5297549) - and why was it deleted?

Comment: I got [another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10461319/external-variable-definition).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A database deadlock that happened at the time of deletion caused some very funky behavior here...it's rare, but it does happen every once in a while in a super-high transaction environment.

Comment: I hear you about lots of transactions causing freaky effects.  If you can tell there was a deadlock, can the info be recovered?

Comment: @Brock - Unfortunately not in this case...the error logs were totally flooded out due to some background maintenance going on today (OS upgrade on the secondary switch stack), so I can't see the exact SQL that was running.

Comment: I've seen this happen, and seen the missing deleter(s) appear a few hours later. Does something else look for this and correct it?